# does the scope of state A reload when we come back from state B?

Tags: angularjs

I have state A and state B.The controllers for both states are different.when we change to state B the scope for state B is created.

1. When we coming back to state A does the scope of state B destroyed?
2. While coming back to state A the does the scope off state A reload?
3. Then how many times does the view reload?

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

> When we come back to state A, does the scope of state B gets destroyed?

Yes, scope of state B gets destroyed and thus, `$destroy` of state B's controller scope gets called. 
(*as described in code snippet below*)

> While coming back to state A, does the scope of state A reload?

Yes, controller A would get reinstantiated, and it will load the template in the given `ng-view` every time.

> Then how many times does the view reload?

The view gets (re)loaded every time we visit any state. The `$scope` of the view emits `$viewContentLoaded` event  ([`ng-view docs`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView)). (*as seen in the snippet below*)

---

Here's a simple implementation of `ui-router` states to explain this information. ([same in plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/MLRWB8?p=preview))

```js
(function() {

  var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"]);

  myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    // For any unmatched url, send to /route1
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1")

    $stateProvider
      .state('route1', {
        url: "/route1",
        template: "<h3>List of Route 1 Items</h3><ul><li ng-repeat='item in items'>{{item}}</li></ul>",
        controller: "route1ctrl"
      })
      .state('route2', {
        url: "/route2",
        template: "<h3>List of Route 2 Things</h3><ul><li ng-repeat='thing in things'>{{thing}}</li></ul>",
        controller: "route2ctrl"
      })
  });

  myapp.controller('route1ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      console.log("route 1 list ctrl loaded")
    });

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      console.log("route 1 destroyed")
    });
  }]);

  myapp.controller('route2ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];

    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
      console.log("route 2 list ctrl loaded")
    });

    $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
      console.log("route 2 destroyed")
    });
  }]);

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

<head>
  <title>AngularJS: UI-Router Quick Start</title>
  <link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body class="container">
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <a class="brand" href="#">Quick Start</a>
      <ul class="nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="route1">Route 1</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="route2">Route 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="well" ui-view></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Angular -->
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.js"></script>

  <!-- UI-Router -->
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>

  <!-- App Script -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <script src="route1.js"></script>
  <script src="route2.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```